# Copy one database to another (existing) database on the same server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, restore

I have a "Live" database and a "Development" database and occasionally, I want to replace the entire contents of the development database with the live data. Ideally, without taking the live database offline. Based on similar questions here and on other forums, I've pieced together this TSQL script:

```
USE MASTER;

BACKUP DATABASE LiveDB TO DISK = '[tempfile]' WITH COPY_ONLY

GO

ALTER DATABASE DevDB SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE 

GO

RESTORE DATABASE DevDB
FROM DISK = '[tempfile]' 
WITH
MOVE 'Live_db'   TO N'...\Dev.mdf',
MOVE N'Live_db_log' TO N'...\Dev_log.ldf',
REPLACE, RECOVERY, NOUNLOAD

GO

ALTER DATABASE DevDB SET MULTI_USER
```

The script runs, I get no error messages, but if I query any table in the development database afterwards, I see the old, unchanged development data.

I get a success message (in German), which translates to:

> RESTORE DATABASE has successfully processed 49809 pages in 16.393 seconds (23.737 MB/s)."

Immediately after the restore, I execute:

```
SELECT * FROM [LiveDB].dbo.SomeTable; 
SELECT * FROM [DevDB].dbo.SomeTable
```

...and I see two completely different results. It looks as if the DevDB hasn't changed at all. I see the same rows I saw before the restore operation.

The live data is not changing; that particular table hasn't changed in the last 2 weeks at least.

What am I doing wrong? I thought `WITH REPLACE` would force `RESTORE` to overwrite the development database.

Comment: Perform your initial backup WITH INIT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspected multiple backups might exist in this backup file.  If you run:

```
RESTORE HEADERONLY from disk = [tempfile]
```

this will show all the backups that are in the file.  You are not restoring the latest backup, use `FILE=X` to restore the appropriate backup.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Chad Mattox's answer.
But to simplify the process, I'd recommend you to use the following t-sql to do the backup

```
BACKUP DATABASE LiveDB TO DISK = '[tempfile]' WITH COPY_ONLY, INIT;
```

By adding **INIT** in your backup script, you will always overwrite the existing one and thus simplify your restore script (by no need to find the latest File [X])

Comment: Thanks, that's what I did, after I realized what the problem was. Chad Mattox's answer helped me understand that, so I'll leave it as the accepted answer

Comment: Glad to hear that everything works for you. For backup itself, another thing I'd recommend is to add COMPRESSION keyword if your sql server edition allows it, i.e. BACKUP DATABASE LiveDB to disk ='[tempfile]' with COPY_ONLY, INIT, COMPRESSION;

Comment: This is likely appropriate for this specific question, but the file may contain good backups that you don't want overwritten.  Either answer gets the job done, using HEADERONLY restore, and File-X allows existing backups to be kept, using INIT overwrites existing backups.  So it all depends on if the existing backups are of any value or not.